# Apps do not show up in paypal's developer dashboard

Tags: paypal

I created app in dashboard.paypal.com in sandbox mode, that was working fine but today when i opened my developer.paypal.com there was no app and paypal is giving errors that "i have no app and no sandbox testing account". While the app is still working on my website (in sandbox mode).

I have two PayPal account 1 is "business account" and other one for personal the app was created on personal account and i got business account just yesterday. this problem is coming after. 
O business account i'm getting same error while trying to create app/sanbox user account.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Same here - I've spent half an hour trying to find a way to notify PayPal tech support, but have failed to navigate their help system.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved now. if you login to developer.paypal.com you will see everything is working normally.